# angular error: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

I am trying to follow codelab of google here:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions-angular/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5

when I try to build the project: ng build --prod, I got the following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/database/interfaces.d.ts(2,26):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

**ng --version give:**

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.5
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.5
@angular/cdk                      5.2.5
@angular/cli                      7.3.5
@angular/fire                     5.1.1
@angular/material                 5.2.5
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.5
@schematics/angular               7.3.5
@schematics/update                0.13.5
rxjs                              5.5.12
typescript                        2.5.3
webpack                           4.29.0
```

> firebase --version
>   6.4.0

**I have tried to search on stackoverflow and try a few things which doesn't work:**

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@4.8.0
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

**or try using newest firebase:**

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

also doesn't work.

I would really appriciate any help,
An

Answer (score 1):

AngularFire has moved to `@angular/fire`. In your package.json you have `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0"`(old version) and `"@angular/fire": "^5.1.1"`

Read [Angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) docs and make sure you use the compatible version

Comment: thank you for your answer, so if i understand correctly what you mean is: The version specify on package.json is old version, so i have to reverse my firebase to earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install firebase dependency as defined in package.json file :

Ex: npm install firebase@4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on login and I'm using nuxt.js, it gave me the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'firebase / compat / app' 17:26:42 Require stack: - /home/script/nuxt-firebase-auth/node_modules/@nuxtjs/firebase/lib/module.js
```

Since you are using angular and I nuxt, only change from the version of dependency

```
"@ nuxtjs / firebase": "^ 8.0.0"
```

To

```
"@ nuxtjs / firebase": "^ 7.6.1"
```